# SAS Code for Filtering records with specific IDs within stream of numbers (IDs) separated by underscores

Tags: filter, sas

I have a field with records like:

```
 1. 1234_2400_800_15001
 2. 8800_1414_2626
 3. 100_3000_8009
 4. 800
 5. 1392_22132_4212
 6. 2213_1700_600
 7. 1392_1100_22134
 8. 2213
```

I need a SAS code to flag or filter all records with IDs 800 & 2213, my code is returning me all 8 records given above, while it should only return exact match from the records with no other preceding or succeeding numbers with the IDs. The correct code should return:

```
1. 1234_2400_800_15001
4. 800
6. 2213_1700_600
8. 2213
```

I tried to find the match via **LIKE** using (_ 800_ or 800_ or _800 or 800) but it's treating "__" as a separate string.

---

Adding code that I used:

```sql
proc sql;
    create table test as select *, 'abc' as Flag1 from work.test
    where
        pd_dt between '01Nov2019'd and '31Oct2020'd and 
        (Case When clm_lvl_abp_id like '%800_%' 
                or clm_lvl_abp_id like '%_800_%' 
                or clm_lvl_abp_id like '%_800%' Then 1
               Else 0
         End)=1;
quit;
```

Comment: We recomend adding some lines of code, so we can supply a sollution that works for you.

Comment: In a narrative the correct use of AND and OR is extremely important.  You want records whose ids list contains *either `800`, or `2213`, or both*.  As a programming specification I would read *`800` & `2213`* as meaning both must be present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regular expression match function `PRXMATCH` to test for simple or complex patterns in strings.

For example:

The regex pattern checks for your target tokens `800` and `2213` for some occurrence within an underscore (`_`) delimited string.

```
data have;
input rownum idlist $50.;
cards;
 1. 1234_2400_800_15001
 2. 8800_1414_2626
 3. 100_3000_8009
 4. 800
 5. 1392_22132_4212
 6. 2213_1700_600
 7. 1392_1100_22134
 8. 2213
;

data want;
  set have;

  place = prxmatch ('/(^|_)(800|2213)($|_)/', strip(idlist));
  if place;
run;
```

For the case of a longer `idlist` and many more target ids to match on, you can use a SQL query with an existential where, leveraging the `indexw` function (@Tom) to find the `idlist`s containing at least one of the target `id`s

Example

```
* 1,000 lists;

data have;
  call streaminit(2021);

  length idlist $200;
  do _n_ = 1 to 1000;
    call missing(idlist);
    do i = 1 to rand('integer', 8);
      id = rand('integer', 1200);
      idlist = catx('_', idlist, id);
    end;
    output;
  end;
  keep idlist;
run;

* 100 targets;

data id_target;
  length id $4;
  call streaminit(2021);
  do _n_ = 1 to 100;
    id = cats(rand('integer',1200));
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select * 
  , countw(idlist,'_') as ids_count
  , (select count(distinct id) from id_target
     where indexw (idlist, trim(id), '_')) as ids_hit
  from have
  where exists (
    select * from id_target
    where indexw (idlist, id, '_')
  )
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: PRXMATCH did a magic. It wasn't just two IDs, but a little lesser than 100 and I had to write the code for those many times with alternative solutions. But from start to end, just 5 lines did the job. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

To the LIKE operator the underscore is a single character wildcard.  To treat is as a regular character you need to escape it.

```
clm_lvl_abp_id like '%800^_%' escape '^'
```

But you will find it is easier to use the [INDEXW() function](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p0korze1qnq4len1mvlb5o98ht1n.htm) to search for the word '800'.  It will return the location where the word started.  You can tell it to treat _ as delimiter.  If the word is not found the returned value is zero.  SAS will treat zero as false and any other value as true.

```
where pd_dt between '01Nov2019'd and '31Oct2020'd
  and indexw(trim(clm_lvl_abp_id),'800','_')
```

Example:

```
data have;
  input rownum idlist $50.;
  found = 0<indexw(trim(idlist),'800','_');
cards;
1 1234_2400_800_15001
2 8800_1414_2626
3 100_3000_8009
4 800
5 1392_22132_4212
6 2213_1700_600
7 1392_1100_22134
8 2213
;
```

Results:

```
rownum    idlist                 found

   1      1234_2400_800_15001      1
   2      8800_1414_2626           0
   3      100_3000_8009            0
   4      800                      1
   5      1392_22132_4212          0
   6      2213_1700_600            0
   7      1392_1100_22134          0
   8      2213                     0
```

Comment: It is better to answered a question twice if you supply two solutions.
Not only can you gain reputation with each, it is clearer for the reader and will make the most appreciated solution appear on top.

Comment: I didn't really answer how to completely fix the problems with the like method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of like, use contains, which does not have any whildcards.
To find IDs at the beginning or end of a string, just add an underscore at each side too.

```sql
data HORST;
    infile datalines truncover;
    format line $55.; 
    input line $;
    datalines;
1234_2400_800_15001
8800_1414_2626
100_3000_8009
800
1392_22132_4212
2213_1700_600
1392_1100_22134
2213
proc sql;
    select * from HORST
    where '_'|| strip(line) ||'_' contains '_800_'
       or '_'|| strip(line) ||'_' contains '_2213_';
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding so quick. While another code is running, quickly wanted to ask if the above would return all these desired records: 1234_2400_800_15001, 800, 2213_1700_600 & 2213

Comment: Did the job with a little tweaking. Thank you so much, you are really kind! I finally did it through PRXMATCH though :-)